# How to Fix a Main Menu (Primary Header) that Switched From Horizontal to Dropdown (WP Astra theme)?

Tags: css, wordpress

My Main Menu (Primary Header) switched from Horizontal to Drop Down. I am using the 'Astra' theme.

Comment: Can you try zooming out? Will you also include the code for the css of the navbar?

Comment: Yes. I've tried zooming my screen, both in and out. It didn't change anything though (I think the problem is that the theme developer updated the Astra theme itself). As for the code, I didn't write any extra code into the website's 'Customize' -> 'Addition CSS' section. I'm using an installed WP theme, called Astra. I believe, what I need to do now, is add additional css code to customize the main menu. But how do I do that?

Comment: Customize a theme by using a 'child theme'. See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and put it in the question itself instead.

Comment: Thanks, wazz, I looked into it, and I don't think I need to use a child theme for this. I'm not changing any php or adding any new functions, or anything like that. I simply need a piece of css code that will convert my drop down menu back to a horizontal menu (the way it was in the 'Before' picture above).

Comment: My navigation is titled "menu_menu". If that's the case, why isn't it working when I add the following code to the Astra theme "Additional CSS" section?            


.menu_menu
{
    display: inline;
}

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding `CSS` will not help since the theme and it's `CSS` and `PHP` rules depend on **breaking points** - *`CSS` breakpoints are points where the website content responds according to the device width, allowing you to show the best possible layout to the user.* 
Since Astra 1.4.0 version you can change the header's breaking point in the customize menu, [refer to this documentation that explains how to do it.](https://wpastra.com/docs/mobile-header-with-astra/#menu-breakpoint)
If your theme is below version 1.4.0 add this `PHP` snippet to your `functions.php` file. [Source](https://wpastra.com/docs/change-astra-header-breakpoint-width/)

```
/**
 * Change the breakpoint of the Astra Header Menus
 * 
 * @return int Screen width when the header should change to the mobile header.
 */
function your_prefix_change_header_breakpoint() {
 return 1120;
};

add_filter( 'astra_header_break_point', 'your_prefix_change_header_breakpoint' );
```

Comment: Thank you, so much, Andrey! I changed the 'Menu Breakpoint' from 3000 to 1050, and it's working again! God bless you!

Comment: @Wardenclyffe Glad to help you! If it solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted (check mark).